# Trying to take a Dictionary and create a data map from the keys and value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to populate an array with 2 elements. ID and Region.

Basically there could be multiple regions (dynamic) and within region an array of IDs, I'm then trying to build the below map from this Dict.

I tried this approach but falling short, maybe this Dict is not the way to go...

```
var tmpMap = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

if (!tmpMap.ContainsKey(region))
    tmpMap.Add(region, new List<string>());

tmpMap[region].Add(id);
```

So this Dict works, and I get the keys and values, but I can't seem to work with this Dict easily,
like I cannot just get all the values for a key.

I'm trying to build the following data element

```
string[] emptyStringArray = new string[0];
string[] IDs = new string[] {
    //I'm trying to list all the IDs from above IDs under region key 
};
data = new
{
    IDs = IDs Array from above,
    NotUsed = emptyStringArray,
    Region = tmpMap[Region][0]
},
{
    IDs = IDs Array from above,
    NotUsed = emptyStringArray,
    Region = tmpMap[Region][1]
};
```

Ideally, this data element will loop through each key and create it.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm stumped.

Comment: `tmpMap[Region].ToArray()` will return an array of all strings added to the `tmpMap` Dictionary with the key `Region`. It's a bit confusing as to why you need an object with a property that has an array of those IDs, and then a property with just one of them (`tmpMap[Region][0]`). If we knew what the end result was being used for, we might be able to steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Why are you using both arrays and list?  Use List and code should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I've fully understood the ask here but it sounds like you just want to get all the ids that relate to a region. If that's the case you can do something like this:

```
var regionsData = new List<RegionData>();

foreach (var region in d.Keys)
{
    var regionData = new RegionData
    {
        Region = region,
        IDs = d[region]
    };

    regionsData.Add(regionData);
}
```

This assumes you have an object to map to (in this case RegionData) like this:

```
public class RegionData
{
    public IList<string> IDs { get; set; }
    public string[] NotUsed { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively you can use LINQ and do something a bit like this and create a IEnumerable of anonymous type:

```
var regionsData = tmpMap.Keys.Select(region => new { IDs = tmpMap[region], Region = region, //any other property you want to create});
```